# MySQL Reservation System with multiple conditions

Tags: php, mysql

I'm writing a PHP/MySQL application for tracking appointments and I'm stuck on locating the next available appointment based on whether any number of conditions are selected.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `appointments` (
`appointmentID` int(9) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`patientID` int(9) unsigned NOT NULL,
`apptTitle` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
`apptDate` date NOT NULL,
`apptTime` time NOT NULL,
`apptLength` int(4) NOT NULL,
`apptStatus` varchar(25) NOT NULL,
`physician` int(9) unsigned NOT NULL,
`apptType` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
`apptInvoice` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
`apptNotes` varchar(1000) NOT NULL,
`apptLocation` varchar(25) NOT NULL,
`apptReminder` int(4) NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`appointmentID`),
 KEY `patientID` (`patientID`),
 KEY `physician` (`physician`),
 KEY `apptStatus` (`apptStatus`),
 KEY `apptLocation` (`apptLocation`),
 KEY `apptType` (`apptType`)
 ) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=4 ;
```

*Side note:* You'll notice my Type, Location, Status fields are varchar's, and they're linked to lookup tables. So, I'm storing the actual value, not an ID for each item (so each lookup table is just the field value as the PK, no ID column). I've done this to reduce joins in the future, but I know this is slightly denormalized.  If this is the wrong way to go, feel free to let me know, I just hadn't found overwhelming evidence one way or the other besides knowing I wouldn't have to do those joins later if I denormalized a bit.  There is "on update" logic in place so if a change is made it will update the values in the appointments table.

The goal here is to show all available appointment slots (these are 15-minute slots, so 12:00am-12:14:59am, 12:15:00am-12:29:59am, etc.). By default, I'd just show all appointment slots for the next X days (probably 14) with no restrictions. But, if a patient wants to see a particular doctor, I'd want to limit to that, or if a doctor only needs a consultation, I can limit the location to a consultation room and not take up an exam room.  Or, we know a follow-up needs to be scheduled for X months, so I can start showing days after that time has elapsed. Or, patient can only make appointments on weekends or after 5pm.

From what I've read, I need some sort of appointment "slots" table, but I'm not sure how I would structure that table so I could compare it against the existing appointments and find my slots.

I know a decent bit about MySQL and I'm always up for a challenge, but I can't seem to wrap my head around how I would do this.  I've looked for similar questions, but none really seemed to cover the amount of customization I'm looking for and I couldn't figure out how to tweak that code to make it work for me.  Hopefully, someone can help me understand where I need to go with this idea!

Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: Write a stored procedure which generates a temporary slot table on the fly, match the existing appointments against that table and filter according to your side conditions. After display, drop the temporary table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think planning for future "reduction of joins" is a good reason. You should be more worried about the future headache you're creating (for you or someone else) with the "update logic". Like you said, fields such as type, location, and status could have metadata relevant to your slots query (type "requires followup in X months", location "is exam room"), so you're going to need to join eventually anyway. Even just to find available locations for a time slot, you'll definitely need to join, if I understand correctly.

I'm guessing a "slot" is like a 5 minute timespan? Eg. 12:00-12:04:59, 12:05-12:09:59, etc?

Like Alex said above, you'll need an "all possible slots" table to left join against (temporary or not).

I'd probably create it permanently on disk, since it's referenced a lot. It sounds like a waste, but the other option is to generate it dynamically each time, which isn't great either.

Then to say find a doctors available slots, something like:

```
SELECT a.* 
FROM slots AS a
LEFT JOIN appointments AS b
ON a.startDate BETWEEN b.apptDate AND DATE_ADD(b.apptDate,INTERVAL b.apptTime MINUTE)
AND b.physician=1234 
WHERE b.appointment IS NULL
```

I can try to help with your other more complicated queries if this sounds like it's on the right track of what you're after.

Comment: Yes, it's 15-minute slots.  I've updated the original question.

I like your reasoning on why I shouldn't be denormalizing. I hadn't thought that far ahead regarding other metadata, thanks for the comments.

As for the slots table, how "big" does that table need to be? From your query, it looks like it has to be every slot for every day. Would it make sense to break the tables into years, so they're not monstrous tables?

Again, thanks for the comments!

Comment: Yes it should be every possible slot that could be reserved. I'd keep adding to it on a schedule as needed (eg every day add any missing slots up to 3 years into the future). It seems big, but it's <3MB (350k datetime rows) for 10 years, you'd be surprised how effienciently MySQL will handle it. Of course, only join on what you need when using it: If a person wants to reserve something next week, your join would limit that range.

Comment: PS: Your comments about "reducing joins" and breaking the table into years tell me you don't trust MySQL to do its job. You really should trust it more, keep table design simple, and be confident that if/when performance issues do come up, you'll have many options.

Comment: PPS: Just noticed I had the tables reversed in the example query, I edited it :)

Comment: gllen, I've been pulled away a bit from this recently, but I'm getting back into the code and I wanted to take you up on your offer for additional assistance with some of the queries.  What's the best way to continue this discussion?  My contact info is in my profile.  Thanks!

Comment: Not seeing the contact info on your profile. If you still need help I added my email address to my "about me".